# historical quotes on decentralised exchange

Tags: solidity, decentralized-exchange, defi

Dears, I'm new in Eth programming, just started to learn Solidity, so need advice.
I want to see historical prices for certain currency pair (say, USDT/DAI) traded on decentralised exchanges like Curve/Balancer/Uniswap.
Could you please suggest, is it technically possible ? If possible, in which direction should I dig to find such info ? (please tell me just main steps how to do it, how to get mentioned data).  Thank you in advance for ANY help !